# TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

My Project is built on Nodejs with TypeScript

I'm getting this compilation error in my Node.js app:

```
 E:\NodeProjects\esshop-mongodb-nodejs\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
    src/posts/post.dto.ts:5:10 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is 
    subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
    5   public author: string;
```

src/posts/post.dto.ts

```
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
 
class CreatePostDto {
  @IsString()
  public author: string;
 
  @IsString()
  public content: string;
 
  @IsString()
  public title: string;
  
}
 
export default CreatePostDto;
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",    
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
    
     
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I installed latest version: [ts-node, typescript]

project repo in github:
https://github.com/barrytestfl/esshop-mongodb-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved by change this options in tsconfig.json:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

**This worked for me**

my tsconfig.json file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```